# C# import xml to listview

Tags: c#, xml, listview

first of all i'm beginner and i'm still learning C#.
At the moment i'm trying to build application in which one of options will be to import xml file to listview.
XML file which i need to import is always in the same format.
Problem which i have is that each node of that xml file have 2 additional attributes inside one node and when i import it to listview it read only first part, it read until it reach new attribute, which is basically part of the same node.

Bellow is XML document from which i need to import following informations:

1. Bank account
2. Customer Name
3. Customer Surname
4. Order ID
5. Return ID
6. Amount
7. Address

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RETURN_POD_EXPORT_INFO>
   <RETURN_TYPE>1</RETURN_TYPE>
   <BRAND>UAUA</BRAND>
   <ECOM_VIRTUAL_STORE>11111</ECOM_VIRTUAL_STORE>
   <COUNTRY_ISO>RS</COUNTRY_ISO>
   <CURRENCY>CCC</CURRENCY>
   <GENERATION_DATE>2020-05-14 05:05:11</GENERATION_DATE>
   <TOTAL_RETURN_AMOUNT>284433.0</TOTAL_RETURN_AMOUNT>
   <TOTAL_RETURN_LINES>3</TOTAL_RETURN_LINES>
   <RETURNS>
      <RETURN>
         <RETURN_ID>133175067</RETURN_ID>
         <ORDER_ID>52061583816</ORDER_ID>
         <RETURN_AMOUNT>2590.0</RETURN_AMOUNT>
         <OPERATION_DATE>2020-05-13 23:27:03</OPERATION_DATE>
         <CUSTOMER_NAME><![CDATA[NAME1]]></CUSTOMER_NAME>
         <CUSTOMER_SURNAME><![CDATA[SURNAME1]]></CUSTOMER_SURNAME>
         <BANK>
            <CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT><![CDATA[165111152438543892]]></CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT>
         </BANK>
         <ADDRESS>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_1><![CDATA[ADDRESS12]]></ADDRESS_LINE_1>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_2 />
            <POST_CODE><![CDATA[11111]]></POST_CODE>
            <CITY><![CDATA[CITY1]]></CITY>
            <PROVINCE />
            <COUNTRY><![CDATA[xx1]]></COUNTRY>
         </ADDRESS>
      </RETURN>
      <RETURN>
         <RETURN_ID>132774698</RETURN_ID>
         <ORDER_ID>52052842870</ORDER_ID>
         <RETURN_AMOUNT>2590.0</RETURN_AMOUNT>
         <OPERATION_DATE>2020-05-13 23:27:03</OPERATION_DATE>
         <CUSTOMER_NAME><![CDATA[NAME2]]></CUSTOMER_NAME>
         <CUSTOMER_SURNAME><![CDATA[SURNAME2]]></CUSTOMER_SURNAME>
         <BANK>
            <CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT><![CDATA[161513116237644624]]></CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT>
         </BANK>
         <ADDRESS>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_1><![CDATA[ADDRESS2]]></ADDRESS_LINE_1>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_2 />
            <POST_CODE><![CDATA[22222]]></POST_CODE>
            <CITY><![CDATA[CITY2]]></CITY>
            <PROVINCE />
            <COUNTRY><![CDATA[xx2]]></COUNTRY>
         </ADDRESS>
      </RETURN>
      <RETURN>
         <RETURN_ID>132957033</RETURN_ID>
         <ORDER_ID>51724252579</ORDER_ID>
         <RETURN_AMOUNT>1290.0</RETURN_AMOUNT>
         <OPERATION_DATE>2020-05-13 23:27:03</OPERATION_DATE>
         <CUSTOMER_NAME><![CDATA[NAME3]]></CUSTOMER_NAME>
         <CUSTOMER_SURNAME><![CDATA[SURNAME3]]></CUSTOMER_SURNAME>
         <BANK>
            <CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT><![CDATA[162519814237644124]]></CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT>
         </BANK>
         <ADDRESS>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_1><![CDATA[ADDRESS3]]></ADDRESS_LINE_1>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_2 />
            <POST_CODE><![CDATA[3333]]></POST_CODE>
            <CITY><![CDATA[CITY3]]></CITY>
            <PROVINCE />
            <COUNTRY><![CDATA[xx3]]></COUNTRY>
         </ADDRESS>
      </RETURN>
      <RETURN>
         <RETURN_ID>133244875</RETURN_ID>
         <ORDER_ID>51729778357</ORDER_ID>
         <RETURN_AMOUNT>2590.0</RETURN_AMOUNT>
         <OPERATION_DATE>2020-05-13 23:27:03</OPERATION_DATE>
         <CUSTOMER_NAME><![CDATA[NAME4]]></CUSTOMER_NAME>
         <CUSTOMER_SURNAME><![CDATA[SURNAME4]]></CUSTOMER_SURNAME>
         <BANK>
            <CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT><![CDATA[169515511237644324]]></CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT>
         </BANK>
         <ADDRESS>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_1><![CDATA[ADDRESSS4]]></ADDRESS_LINE_1>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_2 />
            <POST_CODE><![CDATA[4444]]></POST_CODE>
            <CITY><![CDATA[CITY4]]></CITY>
            <PROVINCE />
            <COUNTRY><![CDATA[XX4]]></COUNTRY>
         </ADDRESS>
      </RETURN>
   </RETURNS>
</RETURN_POD_EXPORT_INFO>
```

Also, bellow is code which i did until now, but problem is that it read only information's about first node "RETURN", it doesn't load information's from all 231 RETURN nodes in XML.

```
foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in doc.SelectNodes("//RETURN"))
{
    
    XmlNode node1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("RETURN_POD_EXPORT_INFO/RETURNS/RETURN/BANK/CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT");
    string bank = node1.InnerText;
    XmlNode node2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("RETURN_POD_EXPORT_INFO/RETURNS/RETURN/CUSTOMER_NAME");
    string name = node2.InnerText;
    XmlNode node3 = doc.SelectSingleNode("RETURN_POD_EXPORT_INFO/RETURNS/RETURN/CUSTOMER_SURNAME");
    string surname = node3.InnerText;
    XmlNode node4 = doc.SelectSingleNode("RETURN_POD_EXPORT_INFO/RETURNS/RETURN/ORDER_ID");
    string orderid = node4.InnerText;
    XmlNode node5 = doc.SelectSingleNode("RETURN_POD_EXPORT_INFO/RETURNS/RETURN/RETURN_ID");
    string returnid = node5.InnerText;
    XmlNode node6 = doc.SelectSingleNode("RETURN_POD_EXPORT_INFO/RETURNS/RETURN/RETURN_AMOUNT");
    string amount = node6.InnerText;
    XmlNode node7 = doc.SelectSingleNode("RETURN_POD_EXPORT_INFO/RETURNS/RETURN/ADDRESS/CITY");
    string city = node7.InnerText;
    
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(bank);
    item.SubItems.Add(name + " " + surname);
    item.SubItems.Add(city);
    item.SubItems.Add("ONLINE POVRAT");
    item.SubItems.Add(orderid);
    item.SubItems.Add(amount);
    item.SubItems.Add(returnid);
    
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I appreciate your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq. You can make the listview datasource the datatable.  Using a datatable preserves the types and makes it easy to add to a control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication172
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Bank account", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Customer Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Customer Surname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Order ID", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("Return ID", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Address_1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Address_2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Post Code", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Providence", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach(XElement xReturn in doc.Descendants("RETURN"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (string)xReturn.Descendants("CUSTOMER_BANK_ACCOUNT").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)xReturn.Element("CUSTOMER_NAME"),
                    (string)xReturn.Element("CUSTOMER_SURNAME"),
                    (long)xReturn.Element("ORDER_ID"),
                    (long)xReturn.Element("RETURN_ID"),
                    (string)xReturn.Element("RETURN_AMOUNT"),
                    (string)xReturn.Descendants("ADDRESS_LINE_1").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)xReturn.Descendants("ADDRESS_LINE_2").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)xReturn.Descendants("POST_CODE").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)xReturn.Descendants("CITY").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)xReturn.Descendants("PROVINCE").FirstOrDefault(),
                    (string)xReturn.Descendants("COUNTRY").FirstOrDefault()
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help.